# How can it be two AndroidManifest.xml files on a single android project

Tags: android, android-manifest, bin

I learned that in every project we have only 1 AndroidManifest.xml file.
BUT I found two of the same file name !!
One is in the root folder, and the other is in the /bin folder...

How come, and what shell I do ?

thx !

Comment: Leave it.  It's auto-generated from the one in the root on build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*project/bin* folder is for compiled (to bytecode) source code and project resources.

Do not worry about it, your IDE is handling content of bin folder automaticly. 
When all code is compilled, your IDE (I think, it is Eclipse) can build your project.

Answer (score 3):

When your project **builds, it creates a copy of itself for execution** in the bin folder.

You can ignore everything in the bin folder as its automatically generated and it **doesn't require any edit directly of you**.

The **only** AndroidManifest.xml you have to worry about is the one in your **root project directory**

Answer (score 1):

One is created by the developer (the one in root folder) and the other one (the one in /bin) is created by eclipse or whatever IDE you are using.

The other one is a compiled binary. This is totally fine. You don't have to do anything. Continue developing!